# Which implementation of a safety stop is more accurate?

Tags: switches, safety

I recently got into an argument with a friend over what the correct implementation of a safety switch for a motor with a spark gap is.

So for intents and purposes, here is the simplified schematic with the engine generator, the fly-back transformer and the spark plug.

[image]

Here is what I think the wiring should be for a safety switch

[image]

I think it should be this way because any modification would cause the engine to not start, which I think is essential.

My friend thinks that an E-stop should be wired like so:

[image]

with the rationale that a faulty switch wouldn't cause an engine out.

In this case, what is more correct, and why?

Comment: What is the point of an E-stop if the engine can run with a faulty E-stop?

Comment: @DKNguyen presumably to stop the engine

Comment: But if it's faulty. Why should the engine be allowed to run at all? E-stop failures would just go unnoticed...until the E-stop is needed most.

Comment: @DKNguyen that's my reasoning, but I think the other side has merit too

Comment: Why would you show a DC motor driving a transformer, knowing that would saturate the core and short out the motor?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75  in this case, it really is a DC motor, and a hobbyist grade engine

Comment: That makes no difference,

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 in that case, the best answer I can provide is because it is the best symbol for the job.

Comment: OK then the question is invalid.  It has false assumptions but say you mean this to  be an AC induction generator,  with no voltage regulator such as a field winding? (alternator)  again not a valid assumption,  so then what is the over-voltage condition ? an arc? a partial discharge?  Yes a shunt with a controlled current limit power resistor is a suitable voltage surge protection, but without current limit is not suitable.  Then there is a holding current spec.  You will find these distributed on the grid with overhead lines very often.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I'm hoping you have the common sense to know what this is, considering you seem to know that it's wrong...

Comment: None of the proposed solutions would be adequate even if the schematic and question was  corrected.  There are too many wrong assumptions and unspecified criteria for protection to ask for a general solution.  It's not done this way. Next time  search for an answer and write a better question. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ac+generator+over+voltage+protection&t=palemoon&ia=web